# conditional sorting of columns based on contents of one column in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have a R `data.frame` of daily stock volumes of 5 stocks for many days:

```
date stock1  stock2  stock3  stock4  stock5
1      350     600    1900    3000     250
2      800     800    1200    4200     400
3      500     600    1500    3500     550
4      600     900    1800    3200     1000  
...
...
```

What I am looking for is a way to get a sorted list of stocks at end of each day, sorted on the volume `numbers(descending ranking)`. I am thinking I can run a for loop for `nrow(df)` and at each iteration, sort the row contents on volume and save the sorted columns headers(stock names) as the expected list for that day. How can I manage to do this. Is it possible to do?

I am a novice in R and programming. I hope my question was clear. Grateful for any help.! thanks.

Comment: I find the problem description unclear. Can your post what you think would be the "right" answer for this data? It seems the connection with the stock name would be lost if you just sorted by row.

Comment: for each date, i want to generate a list of stocks ranked(descending) as per their volumes for the day. so the expected out come would be: for date 1: <stock4, stock3, stock2, stock1, stock5>; date 4: <stock4, stock3, stock2, stock5, stock1>. So, i want to sort stocks conditional to volume rank for each date and save the ranked list of stocks for that date in a temp variable for further use.

Comment: So you want names by day in the order of their volume descending? `apply(dat, 1, function(x) names(dat)[order(x, decreasing=TRUE)])`. It's easier if you make a clear problem statement in natural language first.